# Spring boot Trust All certificate - Unable to find certificate Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

Im Trying to Trust All certificate but still when i try to connec to endpoint , i get the unable to find the cert path in

Please find my code below

I have created a httpurl connection and initiating with the SSL context to load the certificate for the MTLS connection.

Then i try to connect to the endpoint with the httpurl connetion.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OcspHttpClient {

    private final OcspProperties ocspProperties;
    private static final int MAX_CONNECTION_OCSP = 100;

    private SSLSocketFactory getSSLContext() {
        try {

            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "true");
            System.setProperty("http.maxConnections", Integer.toString(MAX_CONNECTION_OCSP));

            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(ocspProperties.getTrustStore().getPath());
            KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            store.load(stream, ocspProperties.getTrustStore().getPassword().toCharArray());

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(store, ocspProperties.getTrustStore().getPassword().toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        public void checkClientTrusted(
                                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }

                        public void checkServerTrusted(
                                java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                    }
            };
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(kms, trustAllCerts, null);

            return SSLContext.getDefault().getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info("Error in creation of the default connection Factory");
            return HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
        }

    }

    public byte[] getResponse(byte[] request, String url) throws IOException {

        HttpsURLConnection con;


        if (StringUtils.isBlank(url) || StringUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
            log.info("url field not set -- setting the value", ocspProperties.getUrl());
            url = ocspProperties.getUrl();
        }
        URL ocspUrl = new URL(url);
        if (ocspProperties.getProxy().isEnabled()) {
            log.info("Proxy Enabled for the ocsp Call");
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(ocspProperties.getProxy().getHost(), ocspProperties.getProxy().getPort()));
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) ocspUrl.openConnection(proxy);
        } else {
            log.info("Proxy Disabled for the ocsp Call");
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) ocspUrl.openConnection();
        }

        con.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLContext());
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/ocsp-request");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/ocsp-response");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(out));
        dataOut.write(request);
        dataOut.flush();
        dataOut.close();
        InputStream in = (InputStream) con.getContent();

        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
}
```

Then get the below error : NOt sure how to trust all cert - Please help on this

```
"message":"PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target","stack_trace":"sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target\r\n\tat sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)\r\n\tat sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)\r\n\tat java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)\r\n\tat sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)\r\n\t..
```

Answer (score 0):

I was returning default context which was the issue.

Fixed as below
return sslContext.getSocketFactory();